# elementary R matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Playing around while trying to refresh my R "knowledge" I did this

```
> a <- matrix(1:20, byrow=TRUE, nrow = 4)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
> b <- a[3:4, 1:2]
> b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   12
[2,]   16   17
> c <- matrix(b, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
> c
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   16
[2,]   12   17
```

Why is `c` different from `b`? What happens under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `matrix` is a `vector` with just dimensions.  So, if you wrap a `matrix` to create another `matrix`, it is considering the values as a `vector` and because the `byrow = TRUE` argument is there, it goes by each column of 'b' (which is true for `matrix`, `data.frame`, `tibble` - `unlist`) and then create the new `matrix` by filling the rows first